# how to determine number of objects in the area

Tags: r, spatial

The problem is to determine number of objects in the area defined by polygon of arbitrary shape. Suppose trees are planted randomly in a rectangular area. The trees are being eaten by some bug and after some time die. Some trees do survive. Both surviving and dead trees form the clusters. In general there are more than 2 clusters. The question is 1) how to detect boundaries between clusters of surviving and dead trees, 2) count the number of trees within each cluster, 3) determine the area of each cluster. I am determining the boundaries using R function boundaries from raster library but got stuck with 2) and 3). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What data do you have or propose to collect?

Comment: ...or is that part of the question also?

Comment: The bug is EAB and data is collected on ash trees.

Comment: Yes, but what kind of data *and in what form?*  Satellite images?  Samples?  Transects?  Quadrat counts?

Comment: year, lat/long of tree, alive/dead status (determined by visual inspection). Data is for several years so one can see how infestation progresses. There are about 400 trees. It is in spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer is triangulation. Triangulate all trees and then break the edges where one vertex is dead tree and another vertex is surviving tree.

Comment: Yes, Delauney triangulation did the job. So simple...